# Can we add a "minor edit" checkbox when editing a question/answer?

Tags: feature-request, editing

This is an extension of [Should making edits bump a question to the top of the list?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/should-making-edits-bump-a-question-to-the-top-of-the-list), which was asked yesterday. I have a tendency to edit a lot of question and answers, which bumps them to the top of the main page of Ask Different. Is it possible to add a "Minor edit" checkbox to the edit page, which will prevent it from floating to the top?

I realize that this may not be technically feasible, but if at all possible, I think this would be an extremely helpful feature.

Comment: +1, if it's technically feasible.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64837/mark-edit-as-minor-to-prevent-bumping

Comment: @JasonSalaz A dupe that is a dupe.

Comment: The SE overlords have [weighed in pretty decisively](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers) on this one. I don't expect we're going to get this.

Comment: I however, don't agree exactly with what they say. I see there point, but why not make it a feature that only user over, say 3K or 5K, can do? If someone is going to take the time to build up a 3K user, they more than likely won't spam the site. You could also have a peer review queue for the minor edits. Just my 2¢ worth...

Comment: I'm not saying you should agree with them. I often don't. But ultimately, when it comes to feature requests, we're requesting and they're deciding, and it sounds like they've rather firmly made up their mind, so I'm just suggesting that this might not be a very fruitful request.

Comment: Also note that this is really asking the same question as [Should making edits bump a question to the top of the list?](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/should-making-edits-bump-a-question-to-the-top-of-the-list), but proposing a specific solution.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that's what I said in my question.

Comment: I have to say, having this and the '[source](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/should-we-be-changing-titles-from-how-to-to-how-can-i-do-i-should-i)' question both hovering around the top of meta really confused me, because the discussion overlaps quite a bit. Add to the fact that it exists elsewhere, primarily because it really is an engine question, not a site specific question, hence the link out to Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good question even though I feel the answer should be no.

Unless someone has a really convincing argument why I'm wrong, I don't see this as something we would want to add. The site already has a timeout built in where repeated edits in a short period of time are considered one edit, so unless altering that interval is appropriate, the current bumping behavior is clearly intended.

Anything that encourages "minor" edits seems to go against the overall message that trivial edits are to be avoided. Wouldn't adding code handling to hide "minor" edits encourage behavior that is explicitly discouraged?

Here relevant MSO questions to our discussion here:

[Feature request: Trivial-edit checkbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102499/feature-request-trivial-edit-checkbox)

[Why are trivial edits discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74430/why-are-trivial-edits-discouraged)

[Can trivial edits not bump the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107528/can-trivial-edits-not-bump-the-question)

[Remove trivial edit restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82893/remove-trivial-edit-restriction)

Comment: I'm not convinced that trivial edits need to be avoided - I think that they are on the SE network precisely because editing bumps to the front page. Wikipedia, for example, has no problems with minor edits. (I've gone into more depth [here](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/should-we-be-changing-titles-from-how-to-to-how-can-i-do-i-should-i/1046#1046))